select oracle geospatial data to insert geometry into a different table
I am trying to select sdo_geometry out of one table and insert it into another.
Having some trouble with how to select the geometry. If I remove the geometry column my code works.
So I assume my trouble is there.
import cx_Oracle

connection_src = cx_Oracle.connect('source connection string')
cursor_src = connection_src.cursor()
cursor_src.arraysize = 500
cursor_src.execute("""select ID, MDSYS.SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(Geometry_column) from src_schema.src_table""")

connection_dst = cx_Oracle.connect('destination connection string')
cursor_dst = connection_dst.cursor()

rows = cursor_src.fetchmany()
cursor_dst.executemany("INSERT INTO dest_schema.dest_table (ID,Geometry_column) VALUES (:1,:2)",rows)

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY got CLOB

if I use this instead: MDSYS.SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT(GEOLOC,1)
I get this error
Errors in file :
OCI-21500: internal error code, arguments: [kgepop: no error frame to pop to], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
OCI-30757: Message 30757 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=OCI


If the source and destination are the same database then use INSERT INTO dest_schema.dest_table (id, geometry_column) SELECT id, geometry_column FROM src_schema.src_table and run it in Oracle using a user that has SELECT permissions on the source and INSERT permissions on the destination. If you do that then you don't need to use any third-party languages (or convert between CLOB and SDO_GEOMETRY).

If they aren't the same database then create a database link between the two.

Alternatively, upgrade to python-oracledb and read the SDO_GEOMETRY object into and out of Python without converting to/from CLOBs. https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-The-New-Wave-of-Scripting.html#bindnamedobj

They are in different databases. Ill try the db link.

You convert it from an SDO_GEOMETRY to a CLOB using the MDSYS.SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY function.
When you want to reverse it convert it from a CLOB back to SDO_GEOMETRY using the MDSYS.SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY function.
import cx_Oracle

connection_src = cx_Oracle.connect('source connection string')
cursor_src = connection_src.cursor()
cursor_src.arraysize = 500
cursor_src.execute(
    "select ID, MDSYS.SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(Geometry_column)"
    " from src_schema.src_table",
)

connection_dst = cx_Oracle.connect('destination connection string')
cursor_dst = connection_dst.cursor()

rows = cursor_src.fetchmany()
cursor_dst.executemany(
    (
        "INSERT INTO dest_schema.dest_table (ID,Geometry_column)"
        " VALUES (:1,MDSYS.SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY(:2))"
    ),
    rows,
)


I received this error: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_JAVA_STP", line 73
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", line 5182
